# How do i make it so python can find a certain duplicate word, count it in a file and make it do something if it does?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I make it so python can find a certain duplicate word, count it in a file and make it execute code if it does?

i've researched everywhere but i cant seem to do it still.

```
file = open("list.txt")
find = "cats"
duplicates = 0

     duplicates+=1
print("duplicates")
```

Comment: Looks like a Homework question

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a list.txt in your directory:

```
cow
cat
rabbit
apple
panda
cat
cow
dog
cat
snake
```

Then, you can use this Python script for reading the file, putting the content in the Python list, and checking the content by using the conditional loop.

```py
file = open('list.txt','r')
lists = [item.rstrip() for item in file.readlines()]
file.close()
duplicates = 0
for item in lists:
    if item == 'cat':
        duplicates += 1
print(duplicates)
```

This is the output:

```
3
```

if you print the `lists` variable. You can see the content of the list below:

```
['cow', 'cat', 'rabbit', 'apple', 'panda', 'cat', 'cow', 'dog', 'cat', 'snake']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain a Dictionary to count duplicates.

```py
Dup = {}
with open("file.txt",'r') as f:
    Lines = f.readlines()
    for line in Lines:
        text = line.strip().split()
        for word in text:
            if word in Dup:
                Dup[word]+=1
            else:
                Dup[word]=1
x = "cats"
if x in Dup:
    print(Dup[x])
else:
    print(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a function, that will handily print your word along with its duplicates:

```
def findDuplicates(file,word):
    words = {}
    with open(file,'r') as fp:
        lines = fp.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            for w in line.split():
                if w not in words:
                    words[w] = 1
                else:
                    words[w] += 1
    frequency = 0
    if word in words:
        frequency = words[word]
    
    print(f"The word \"{word}\" was found {frequency} times in the text")
```

This function uses a **hash-table**, by first opening the file, reading through all the lines and converting all the lines in an array of words, by using the `.split()` method.

It will then iterate through this array of words and check if they were met before. If they were not, it will add `1`, to the dictionary, for the key of that word.

If instead, the word was indeed met before, it will increase the corresponding number by 1.

You can use the function like shown, assuming to have a `lorem.txt` like this:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer and adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis and dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium and quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec and pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo.
```

You can call the function by giving as arguments the path of the file you want to open and the word you are looking to get duplicates for, like:

```
findDuplicates("lorem.txt", "and")
```

And the output will be:

```
The word "and" was found 4 times in the text
```

Bonus tip: if you want to make it **case-insensitive**, when your scripts counts the occurences within the text, add this line:

`w = w.lower()`

Just above:

`if w not in words:`

If you also want your function to be able to input case-insensitive words to look for, modify the last if statement with:

```
if word.lower() in words:
    frequency = words[word.lower()]
```

And you will get:

```
[In]: findDuplicates("lorem.txt", "AND")
[Out]: The word "AND" was found 4 times in the text
```